# Access QML nested variable member from custom Label

Tags: qt, label, qml

I have the following custom `Label`:

```
import QtQuick 2.3
import QtQuick.Controls 1.4

Label
{
    anchors.centerIn: parent
    text: "DashboardLabel!"
    font.pixelSize: 22
    font.italic: true
    color: "steelblue"

    Rectangle
    {
        id: rectangle
    }
}
```

I'm trying to change the position of the label by accessing the x and y variables from `rectangle`:

```
import QtQuick 2.3
import QtQuick.Controls 1.4
import CustomGraphics 1.0

Item
{
    anchors.centerIn: parent

    CustomLabel
    {
        id: customLabel
        width: 100
        height: 100

        rectangle.x: 200
    }
}
```

It doesn't seem to be working since my custom `Label` is not moved. Should I use the `property` feature? Here is the error I'm getting:

```
Cannot assign to non-existent property "rectangle"
```

**EDIT**: I've just tried to add `property alias rect: rectangle` in order to access `x` with `rect.x`. I do not get any errors but nothing appears on the window.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't access the private properties of the child element like that. You have to create `alias` in order for the subclass to access them. Try this

```
import QtQuick 2.3
import QtQuick.Controls 1.4

Label
{
    property alias childRect: rectangle
    anchors.centerIn: parent
    text: "DashboardLabel!"
    font.pixelSize: 22
    font.italic: true
    color: "steelblue"

    Rectangle
    {
        id: rectangle
        width: 100
        height: 100
    }
}
```

and then

```
import QtQuick 2.3
import QtQuick.Controls 1.4
import CustomGraphics 1.0

Item
{
    anchors.centerIn: parent

    CustomLabel
    {
        id: customLabel
        width: 100
        height: 100

        childRec.x: 200
    }
}
```

---

*UPDATE* as OP changed the description

You haven't set `width` and `height` properties for the rectangle. See my edit.